# Shutdown on LAN between Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I have 2 laptops, a Windows 7 machine and the other running Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to figure out how to write a batch script for Windows that would allow me to shutdown both computers simultaneously.

Can I use the WOL functions to accomplish this or do I need some sort of deamon running on the Linux machine? I really don’t want to have a client like RDP or VNC constantly running.

Comment: You can connect via SSH like [here](http://z-computer-z.blogspot.ro/2010/01/remote-shutdown-and-remote-reboot-on.html).

Comment: Thank you Cornelius. this is a step in the right direction. I have openssh server running on the ubuntu machine and putty running on the windows machine. AT this point I'm not sure how to go about scripting to allow this to be a 1-click-all-shutdown solution, Is there a better option than putty or can i use the command line for predefined commands using putty wothout the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `shutdown.sh` containing:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Create your `shutdown.bat` file

```
putty.exe -ssh -l user -pw password 1.2.3.4 -m shutdown.sh
SHUTDOWN /s /t 60 /c "Shutdown in progress"
```

Lookup ssh-keys to allow key-based rather than password based login from your script to the Linux box.

Note, you will need to feed sudo a password by default, which is horribly insecure to do in a script. (Anyone who finds the script can now root your other box.) The workaround is to enable the `shutdown` command to run without requiring root. See the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361988/why-do-we-need-to-be-root-in-terminal-for-shutdown-and-restart) to enable this. The best way is to add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%sudo ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
```

But be aware, this allows any user to reboot your machine.

Comment: Noob question: Where so I save the shutdown.sh file? (Note: It's ok to have the root password in the script, as it's being executed from an encrypted partition that is only mounted when I'm near/on the computer.

Comment: Put it in the same place you're executing `shutdown.bat` from, and ensure you have the path to `putty.exe` set in `%PATH%`. And, no, you don't want plain-text passwords setting in scripts, even if the hard drive is encrypted. It's not encrypted to the OS, and what if your OS is compromised? If you're going to start learning remote administration, start learning about security.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for your help ( and the security advice)

Comment: @Banquo please mark the answer correct if it worked for you, thanks and glad to help